# Subtract value from other table using Inner Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to subtract a value by another value from another table (Sorry for the mouthful)
But the SQL which i've developed keeps throwing the same error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM products INNER JOIN order_details ON products.ItemID = order_details.Item' at line 2`

This is my code:

```
UPDATE products SET Quantity = (products.Quantity - order_details.Quantity)
FROM products
INNER JOIN order_details
ON products.ItemID = order_details.ItemID
WHERE order_details.OrderID = 95 AND products.ItemID = order_details.ItemID;
```

Its just code for when someone buys an item, it's supposed to reduce the quantity in the products table by the number of whatever they've bought. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: MySQL does not support FROM clause in UPDATE. See Manual Reference for correct syntax.

Comment: If this is done at the same time as the order `INSERT` into the db... Why even bother with the `JOIN`? Just subtract the number ordered from `products` table? `UPDATE products SET Quantity = Quantity - ? WHERE ItemID = ?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `join` is part of the `update` not of the `SET`clause:

```
UPDATE products INNER JOIN order_details
ON products.ItemID = order_details.ItemID
SET Quantity = (products.Quantity - order_details.Quantity)
WHERE order_details.OrderID = 95;
```